# Show suggestions in a list one by one

Tags: php, arrays, search-engine, search-suggestion

How can I show suggestions in a list one by one?

When I run the below codes, I get this as my suggestion when I type in `google`: `["Google", "Gmail", "Google Maps"]`.

I want the suggestions to be shown in this way:

```
Google
Gmail
Google Maps
```

How can I do this?

If possible, please explain my mistakes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning `json` formatted objects in `suggestion.php` but using it as `HTML` in `script_suggestion.php`.

Either update `suggestion.php` to return a HTML snippet or have the javascript in `script_suggestion.php` decode the json and use that to build the suggestions.

Example HTML output:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($arr as $suggestion){
    echo "<li>".$suggestion."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: How can I do this? I want the HTML option.

Comment: @HFial1964 You can loop over `arr` and echo out a list.

Comment: @HFial1964 I've added an example.

Comment: @HFial1964 I'd recommend familiarising yourself with PHP a bit more before trying something as involved as this.